# Create two tables in same schema.sql H2

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I'm using Spring boot, and I have to initiate two tables for testing. I'm using the `schema.sql` inside the resource folder. But when I'm trying to create two tables in the same script and run the app, it can't load the application context.

Here is my `schema.sql` which I have placed at resource folder:

```
CREATE TABLE JobStatus_FO
(
   id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   businessDate timestamp NOT NULL,
   label varchar(50),
);
CREATE TABLE JobStatusDetails_FO
{
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(50),
};
```

Comment: Creating two tables should work fine though. Is there any error within the log? If so, please provide that since that information would be essential to solve the issue. Also, I'm noticing trailing comma's after the last field for each table, no clue if H2 supports that, but that would be my initial guess.

Comment: Please provide spring boot version & complete error message you are getting at load time..

Answer (score 1):

Please find the correct scripts as

```
    CREATE TABLE JobStatus_FO
(
   id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   businessDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
   label VARCHAR(50),
   KEY id(id)
);
CREATE TABLE JobStatusDetails_FO
(
  id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR(50)
);
```

Your syntax is not correct of create table .
1) In your scripts you have used extra comma "," before closing parentheses
2) Auto increment column should be used as a key in table
3) Curly braces "{" is not used within create table.

Hope this will work in to your project.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still getting the same error. In the data.sql file I can insert data in both tables right?

Comment: Yes In data.sql file you can insert data in both tables, but query should be error free. Can I know what is in your data.sql and what error you are getting exactly?

Comment: The error in data.sql was that i was duplicating the id and having a longer string (more than 50). But the main thing was that I used {} instead of () generating the second table. I don't know why I used those :P

Thanks!!